# Unable to use a certificate to login to a website via com-interop in Windows 10 1809

Tags: .net, excel, vba, https, com-interop

The C# code below, which logs in to a website,

- Works when called on computer A from Excel 2010 VBA via com-interop
- Works when called on computer B from a C# console application, but
- Fails when called on computer B from Excel 2010 VBA via com-interop

The main difference between computer A and computer B is that computer A has windows 10 version 1803, whereas computer B has windows 10 version 1809.  Both computers have Studio 2017, and in all cases the target .Net Framework is 4.6.2.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

[Guid("97E1D9DB-8478-4E56-9D6D-26D8EF13B100")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IToExcel {
    string Do();
}

[Guid("BBF87E31-77E2-46B6-8093-1689A144BFC6")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Main : IToExcel {
    private const string XAPP_ID = "...";
    private const string USERNAME = "...";
    private const string PASSWORD = "...";
    private const string CERT_FILE = @"...";
    private const string CERT_PASSWORD = "...";
    private const string WEBSITE = "https:// ...";

    public string Do() {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(new Uri(WEBSITE));
        request.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.Timeout = request.ReadWriteTimeout = 20000;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.Proxy = null;
        // setup headers
        System.Net.WebHeaderCollection whc = new System.Net.WebHeaderCollection {
            { "X-Application", XAPP_ID },
            { System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset, "utf-8" },
            { System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate" }
        };
        request.Headers.Add(whc);
        // setup certificate
        System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 m_x509certificate = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(CERT_FILE, CERT_PASSWORD);
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(m_x509certificate);
        // do call
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.Default)) {
                writer.Write("username=" + USERNAME + "&password=" + PASSWORD);
            }
        }
        string responseData = string.Empty;
        using (System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)) {
                    responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return responseData;
    }

}
```

In all cases a little JSON object is returned, where the JSON object has a field called "loginStatus".  When it works, "loginStatus"="SUCCESS", but when it fails "loginStatus"="CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED".

I tried looking at all the settings in System.Net.ServicePointManager but in all cases the settings were the same:

- ReusePort: False
- ServerCertificateValidationCallback:
- DnsRefreshTimeout: 120000
- EnableDnsRoundRobin: False
- Expect100Continue: True
- UseNagleAlgorithm: True
- MaxServicePointIdleTime: 100000
- DefaultConnectionLimit: 2
- MaxServicePoints: 0
- SecurityProtocol: Tls, Tls11, Tls12
- CheckCertificateRevocationList: False
- EncryptionPolicy: RequireEncryption

Beyond that, I don't know what else to check.  Upgrading from .Net 4.6.2 to 4.7.1 had no effect, the results were the same.

I had wondered whether this is a bug in Windows 1809, but since it works when called directly in a .Net console application I assume it's some subtle configuration issue.  Can anyone help me get this working from Excel 2010 on computer B ?

**Update 8-Feb-2019**

As suggested in the comments, I used Fiddler to review the structure of the https calls that are being made to the website.  The two that work look identical, and the one that fails looks slightly different:

Calls that work OK

- TLS extension ec_point_formats = uncompressed [0x0]
- TLS extension encrypt_then_mac (RFC7366) not specified
- TLS extension renegotiation_info = 0
- Cipher TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV not specified

Failed call

- TLS extension ec_point_formats = uncompressed [0x0], ansiX962_compressed_prime [0x1], ansiX962_compressed_char2  [0x2]
- TLS extension encrypt_then_mac (RFC7366) = empty
- TLS extension renegotiation_info not specified
- Cipher TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV specified

But now I have that information, I'm not sure if it helps.  Perhaps the calls that work are both generated by the same low level code (in spite of the fact that they're on different versions of Windows 10), and the call that fails is generated by different low level code.

**Update 10-Feb-2019**

When calling from Excel via com-interop, I made the code execute the EXE in a new AppDomain instead of calling the login code directly.  And when I did that, the EXE failed to work and produced the same output as if I'd called the login code directly.

Below is some of the Visual Studio Output window which shows the order in which DLLs are loaded when the EXE file runs, just before the login code executes.  The biggest difference between both the scenarios which succeed and the scenario which fails is that the scenario which fails never loads C:\Windows\System32\ncryptprov.dll.  Does anyone know what causes that DLL to be loaded?

…

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msisip.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\coml2.dll'   ---   LOADED EARLIER FROM EXCEL

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wshext.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\AppxSip.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\tdh.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\xmllite.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\OpcServices.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mintdh.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\urlmon.dll'   ---   LOADED EARLIER FROM EXCEL

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mintdh.dll'

(Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mintdh.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\iertutil.dll'   ---   LOADED EARLIER FROM EXCEL

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\pwrshsip.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\EsdSip.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\userenv.dll'   ---   LOADED EARLIER FROM EXCEL

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dpapi.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dnsapi.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\secur32.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sspicli.dll'   ---   LOADED EARLIER FROM EXCEL

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\schannel.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mskeyprotect.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncrypt.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntasn1.dll'

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncryptprov.dll'   ---   NOT EVER LOADED FROM EXCEL

(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ncryptsslp.dll'

At this point the C# code executes

**Update 12-Feb-2019**

Many many thanks to [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) for telling me how to setup the System.Net diagnostics.  Running the diagnostics on computer B, the "System.Net information" rows that get output for the two cases start off the same, but eventually there is a difference.  This is the output from the Console EXE file on Computer B (i.e. the case that works):

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] Current OS installation type is 'Client'.
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] RAS supported: True
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] Associating HttpWebRequest#21454193 with ServicePoint#34640832
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] Associating Connection#43332040 with HttpWebRequest#21454193
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] Connection#43332040 - Created connection from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:53002 to YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:443.
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] TlsStream#54444047::.ctor(host=<TargetWebSite>, #certs=1, checkCertificateRevocationList=False, sslProtocols=Tls12)
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] Associating HttpWebRequest#21454193 with ConnectStream#20234383
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] HttpWebRequest#21454193 - Request: POST /api/certlogin HTTP/1.1
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] ConnectStream#20234383 - Sending headers
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719::.ctor(hostname=<TargetWebSite>, #clientCertificates=1, encryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] Enumerating security packages:
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     Negotiate
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     NegoExtender
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     Kerberos
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     NTLM
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     TSSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     pku2u
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     CloudAP
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     WDigest
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     Schannel
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     Default TLS SSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268]     CREDSSP
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719 - Attempting to restart the session using the user-provided certificate: [Version]
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719 - Left with 1 client certificates to choose from.
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719 - Trying to find a matching certificate in the certificate store.
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719 - Locating the private key for the certificate: [Version]
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719 - Certificate is of type X509Certificate2 and contains the private key.
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719::.AcquireClientCredentials, new SecureCredential() (flags=(ValidateManual, NoDefaultCred, SendAuxRecord, UseStrongCrypto), m_ProtocolFlags=(Tls12Client), m_EncryptionPolicy=RequireEncryption)
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] AcquireCredentialsHandle(package = Microsoft Unified Security Protocol Provider, intent  = Outbound, scc     = System.Net.SecureCredential)
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = <TargetWebSite>, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=184, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 227c85a89b0:2449d0deff0, targetName = <TargetWebSite>, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=CredentialsNeeded).
```

However, when running from Excel 2010 via com-interop, instead of those last 4 InitializeSecurityContext lines, there are 6 InitializeSecurityContext lines as follows:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = (null), targetName = <TargetWebSite>, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffer length=0, Out-Buffer length=184, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 8a8e2f0:2449d0def90, targetName = <TargetWebSite>, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 8a8e2f0:2449d0def90, targetName = <TargetWebSite>, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=ContinueNeeded).
```

The first two InitializeSecurityContext lines are the identical, so presumably crucial difference is on the third InitializeSecurityContext line, where the console EXE has

context = 227c85a89b0:2449d0deff0

but the failed run via com-interop executino has

context = 8a8e2f0:2449d0def90

After that, things don't look the same, as one would expect.  Does anyone know what that difference means, and how to make the difference go away so that the com-interop execution behaves in the same way as the com-interop execution?

**Update 13-Feb-2019**

I have posted more of the diagnostic output on [an MSDN forum](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35954da6-5fa7-4685-b40b-60110df0903e/systemnethttpwebrequest-fails-to-logon-to-a-website-via-cominterop-in-windows-10-1809).

Comment: Have you compared the requests with Fiddler or online sandbox like [webhook.site](https://webhook.site)?

Comment: Thanks @omegastripes , no, I am not an expert in this so I was unaware of both.  I will try :-)

Comment: I'd focus on the Console vs Excel scenario on the same machine. I guess code using Excel and code using Console doesn't use the same .NET Framework layer underneath, so inner settings are probably different. There's been a great disturbance in the SSL force over the past months. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls can you try to define ServicePointManager.SecurityProtol = 0 ?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.clientcertificates?view=netframework-4.7.2): An application can add a certificate to a collection, but might not have access rights to it. To use a certificate contained in the collection, the application must have the same access rights as the entity that issued the certificate.

Comment: Excel needs the access rights to the certificate on the computer B as well. Check the access rights of Excel on computer A and set them on B accordingly.  [How to view certificates](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-view-certificates-with-the-mmc-snap-in).

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for the suggestions.  I am using an Excel.exe.config file to specify the .Net framework to use (now 4.7.2), and I've also tried using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtol=0 .  But it still doesn't work, and Fiddler still shows me the same subtle differences in the TLS extensions and one difference in the Ciphers.

Comment: @dee thanks for the suggestions, however the certificate that I'm using isn't stored in the certificate manager, it's just a file on my C: hard drive.  And using Visual Studio debug mode I can see that the certificate is loaded properly in all cases.

Comment: How do you configure your .config, do you use the 'sku' attribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/startup/supportedruntime-element)? Are you sure this .config is used (for excel)? Have you checked both console & excel processes (using a tool such as Process Explorer from sysinternals) to see if they have the same .dll loaded (well the ones related to .NETmostly)? Also, do the console and Excel run as the same bitness (x86 vs x64).

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I'm using the 'sku' attribute.  I've checked that  the .config is being used by Excel by setting a non-default value for one of the ServicePointManager settings, and checking in Visual Studio debug mode that the setting is there.  I reported in today's update that there is just one DLL that's used by my console process that's not used at all by Excel, however regarding all other DLLs used by the console process Excel uses the identical versions (and of course there are various DLLS that Excel uses that are not used by the console process).  All processes are x64.

Comment: Is there's only 1 certificate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528973/force-httpwebrequest-to-send-client-certificate otherwise you can try to add some traces https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808016/how-do-i-see-the-raw-http-request-that-the-httpwebrequest-class-sends .ncryptprov is Microsoft Key Storage Provider (KSP, an essential library for CNG, modern Windows crypto) thing is it looks like both codes take different crypto routes for some reason...

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks for that, it seems very helpful because using the diagnostics I've been able to work out where the two executions diverge.  But the difference in the two diagnostic outputs seems quite obscure.  I've edited the question, see "Update 12-Feb-2019".  If you have any ideas on what that means, or who might know, then it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If both startups look the same, it's good news (sort of...), but, the traces should exhibit some error in the end? Or where does that "loginStatus"="CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED" comes from? is it a custom message sent by your server?

Comment: Your MSDN traces show you don't end up with the same certificate issuer. I bet your server doesn't like the excel one. Or stop your anti virus and see if it wouldn't fix your issue

Comment: @SimonMourier thank you very much.  I disabled Kaspersky and the problem disappeared.  Completely bizarre, because the identical version of Kaspersky and identical version of Excel with my identical C# program didn't cause the problem on computer A (with Windows 10 1803).  I don't know if someone with a stackoverflow reputation as high as yours needs the 200 bonus here, but if you want it I think you have to post the answer for me to award it to you :-) .  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on the C# console vs Excel 2010 issue (same machine, both running as 64-bit processes), traces have been added as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683524/403671

The initial traces from Excel and Console are exactly the same (see the question for more detail). But the last traces (posted to MSDN) exhibit this:

Console:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] Remote certificate: [Version] V3
[ Lots of lines describing a certificate with [Subject]=<TargetWebSite>, [Issuer]=HydrantID SSL ICA G2, etc]
System.Net Information: 0 : [35268] SecureChannel#47891719 - Remote certificate was verified as valid by the user.
```

Excel:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] Remote certificate: [Version] V3
[ Lots of lines describing a certificate with [Subject]=<TargetWebSite>, [Issuer]=Kaspersky, etc]
System.Net Information: 0 : [39988] SecureChannel#2383799 - Remote certificate was verified as valid by the user.
```

It shows the certificate used in Excel is now issued by Kaspersky, which turns out to be the anti-virus product running on the PC. In fact, it's a Kaspersky product security feature to [intercept communications](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104495/which-ca-issued-certificate-for-https-www-google-com), and this causes numerous issues, like [KIS Interfering with Git](https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/395220-kis-interfering-with-git/), for example.

Once this anti-virus is removed everything works as expected.