# How to make an HTTP Get request along with SslStream & TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, sslstream

In my application I am using the below code to validate the client certificate

```
public static async Task<string> CallApi(string url, Context context)
{
    var hostName = "mytestapp.azurewebsites.net";
    var port = 443;

    Stream keyin = Application.Context.Assets.Open("Server.pfx");
    var password = "pass123";
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        keyin.CopyTo(memStream);
        var certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection(new X509Certificate2(memStream.ToArray(), password));
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Create a TCP/IP client socket.
            // machineName is the host running the server application.
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostName, port);
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
            // Create an SSL stream that will close the client's stream.
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                client.GetStream(),
                false,
                ValidateServerCertificate);

            // The server name must match the name on the server certificate.
            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName, certificates, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                if (e.InnerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                client.Close();
                return;
            }
        });
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

after successful authentication, I would like to make and HTTP get request.

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName, certificates, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);
```

After this statement. Say for example I need to call below http Get call

**https://mytestapp.azurewebsites.net/api/GetUserProfile?userId="Sooraj"**

How I can invoke this call? Or is it possible to implement the same?

Please help

Comment: It may be easier to use a WebClient instead of your own TcpClient. You can allow WebClient to use a certificate and SSL. Sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066489/how-can-you-add-a-certificate-to-webclient-c

Comment: Another alternative might be HttpWebRequest. Here is a sample with a client certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528973/force-httpwebrequest-to-send-client-certificate

Comment: Otherwise, if you continue using TcpClient, I believe you would need to write your own HTTP headers and request to the stream, and parse the response manually.

Comment: Sadly I am using Mono / Xamarin. I can't use WebClient. There is a known limitation in Mono.Net

Comment: Could you please let me know more about continuing with TCP Client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
try
                    {
                        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostName, certificates, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[5120];
                        int bytes;
                        var pqr = string.Format("GET {0}  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {1}\r\n\r\n", url, "mytestapp.azurewebsites.net");
                        byte[] request = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pqr);
                        sslStream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
                        var ppp =  ReadStream(sslStream);
                        sslStream.Flush();

                    }
                    catch (AuthenticationException e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
                        if (e.InnerException != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
                        client.Close();
                        return;
                    }


 private static string ReadStream(Stream stream)
        {
            byte[] resultBuffer = new byte[2048];
            string value = "";
            //requestStream.BeginRead(resultBuffer, 0, resultBuffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadAsyncCallback), new result() { buffer = resultBuffer, stream = requestStream, handler = callback, asyncResult = null });
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    int read = stream.Read(resultBuffer, 0, resultBuffer.Length);
                    value += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultBuffer, 0, read);

                    if (read < resultBuffer.Length)
                        break;
                }
                catch { break; }
            } while (true);
            return value;
        }
```

It will give you the response with all set of data. and later we need to parse the required information.