# Can I perform a https request with curl and a pfx?

Tags: windows, curl, https, command-line

It is possible to perform a curl request to a website under https if all I have is a pfx? When I run:

```
curl -k -v --insecure --cert client.pem:1234 --key privkey.pem "https://testurl/service/RESTService/GetCustomers"
```

I get the error:

> failed to import cert file 0x80092002.

There is something wrong with the exported pem and maybe it is causes by the pfx which is not possible to export.

EDIT:
[image: KeyStore Explorer]

EDIT 2:
[image]

Comment: What is contained in the pfx files? A certificate (chain) of the server or a private key plus certificate for HTTPS client authentication?

Comment: How can I check it? I own the pfx file and if I install it I am able to access to the url and log in correctly, so must be complete, the problem is when I split it to execute curl.

Comment: You ask the person you got the pfy file from or you look into the pfx file e.g. using a tool like https://keystore-explorer.org and see if it contains just a certificate chain or also a private key.

Comment: I installed KeyStore Explorer as you told me but I don't know how to identify if it includes both the certificate chain and the private key, I will edit to add a screenshot.

Comment: The screen shot only shows the certificate extensions. In the main view select the first column and look at the tooltip.

Comment: I don't understand you fully, sorry, maybe my keystore version is different, but this is what you meant?

Comment: The keystore seems to contain a key pair thus it is designed to be used for https client authentication. Inside KeystoreExplorer you can open context menu of the entry -> Export -> Export Key pair -> PEM. These files should be usable by curl.

Comment: Not working when I run curl "https://www.myurl.com" --cert keypair.pem:1111, at least and thank to you, I can be sure that the certificate is correct, so it must be a curl problem apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to make it work so I found an example here in the communuty with C# which also suits me because I intended to create a bat with curl and I will replace it with a exe.
Thanks for your help Robert.
Post link: [Force HttpWebRequest to send client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528973/force-httpwebrequest-to-send-client-certificate)